# UITableView tableView(_:didEndEditingRowAt:) not called if rapidly tapping during swipe

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with an `editAction` that is accessible by swiping left.

It seems like there is a built in `UITableView` functionality where if you swipe the cell to show the edit action, and then later tap anywhere in the tableView, the action is swiped closed automatically, and `didEndEditingRowAt` is called to notify the delegate that editing is over.

However, the problem I am seeing is that sometimes, if you swipe to the left and then really quickly after the swipe (when only a tiny piece of the edit action is visible and the animation is in progress), you tap anywhere else on the screen, the edit action is closed but the `didEndEditingRowAt` is not called!

So, with the following code, we end up with the tableView being in Edit Mode, but no view swiped open, and the last line printed being `Will Edit`, confirming that `didEndEditingRowAt` was never called.

```
  class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

  let tableView = UITableView()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view = tableView
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "foo")
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = false
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: " Remove") {(_, indexPath) in print("OK") }
    return [deleteAction]
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {}

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {}

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
    return indexPath
  }


  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willBeginEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("Will edit")
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath?) {
    print("Did end edit")
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 80
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "foo") ?? UITableViewCell()
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
  }
}
```

Now, this only happens sometimes, and its a bit hard to get the timing right, but its definitely reproducible.

Here is a link to the whole demo: https://github.com/gregkerzhner/SwipeBugDemo

Am I doing or expecting something wrong here?  In my real project I have code that fades the other cells to focus on the cell being currently edited, and I end up in a bad state where the other cells get faded, but the focused cell doesn't have any edit actions open.

Comment: I was surprised that I was able to replicate this in my own project, albeit only one in ten tries. To me this seems like a bug on Apple's part, which I am usually hesitant to say.   Personally, I don't see that a user would ever do this on purpose if they are using the app normally.

Comment: yeah, perhaps related to http://www.openradar.me/19411256

Comment: I wonder if there are any workarounds short of building my own swipe code.  Otherwise this isn't getting past QA!

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely a bug in UITableView, it stays in "editing" state even if the swipe bounced back (e.g. if you swipe it just a little bit).

Good news is that you can employ some of UITableViewCell's methods to find a workaround. 
UITableViewCell has corresponding methods that notify of action-related state changes:

```
func willTransition(to state: UITableViewCellStateMask)
func didTransition(to state: UITableViewCellStateMask)
func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool)
var showingDeleteConfirmation: Bool { get }
```

The transition methods are called when the transition (and animation) begins and ends. When you swipe, `willTransition` and `didTransition` will be called (with state `.showingDeleteConfirmationMask`), and `showingDeleteConfirmation` will be `true`. `setEditing` is also called with `true`.

While this is still buggy (cell shouldn't successfully become editing unless you actually unveiled the buttons), `didTransition` is a callback where you get a chance to check whether the actions view is indeed visible. I don't think there's any robust way to do this, but maybe simply checking that cell's `contentView` takes most of its bounds would be enough.

Comment: I am going to accept this as the answer because its seems less hacky than the suggestion by @ncke

Comment: @gregkerzhner Which of those callbacks is coming through successfully in your edge case though? I'm afraid they're going into the same black hole as didEndEditing...

Answer (score 2):

So in the end, the working solution ended up a bit different from what @ncke and @hybridcattt suggested.

The problem with @ncke's solution is that the `func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)` does not get called during this swipe/tap interaction, so the workaround never gets called.

The problem with @hybridcattt's solution is that those `UITableViewCell` callbacks get called too early, so if you do the swipe rapid tap action, the `UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationView` is still part of the subviews of the cell when all of those callbacks get called.

The best way seems to be to override the `willRemoveSubview(_ subview: UIView)` function of `UITableViewCell`.  This gets called reliably every time the `UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationView` gets removed, both during normal swipe close, and also in this buggy swipe rapid tap scenario.

```
  protocol BugFixDelegate {
    func editingEnded(cell: UITableViewCell)
  }

  class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    weak var bugFixDelegate: BugFixDelegate?
    override func willRemoveSubview(_ subview: UIView) {
      guard String(describing: type(of: subview)) == "UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationView" else {return }
      endEditing(true)
      bugFixDelegate.editingEnded(cell: self)
    }
  }
```

As @hybridcattt and @ncke suggested, in your controller you can hook into this delegate and send the missing events to the `UITableView` and `UITableViewDelegate` like

```
class DummyController: UIViewController {
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier) as? CustomCell else {return UITableViewCell()}

    cell.bugFixDelegate = self

  }
}

extension DummyController: BugFixDelegate {
  //do all the missing stuff that was supposed to happen automatically
  func editingEnded(cell: UITableViewCell) {
    guard let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPath(for: cell) else {return}
    self.tableView.setEditing(false, animated: false)
    self.tableView.delegate?.tableView?(tableView, didEndEditingRowAt: indexPath)
  }
}
```

Comment: Great tip, thanks! In my case, it was enough to end editing of the tableView with `tableView.setEditing(false, animated: false)`. This also called `tableView: didEndEditingRowAt indexPath:`, and everything was fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not saying that this is the best thing ever, but if you want a workaround this could be a start:

```swift
extension UITableView {

    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        for cell in self.visibleCells {
            if cell.isEditing && (cell.subviews.count < 3 || cell.subviews[2].frame.origin.x < 30.0) {

                print("\(cell) is no longer editing")
                cell.endEditing(true)
                if let indexPath = self.indexPath(for: cell) {
                    self.delegate?.tableView?(self, didEndEditingRowAt: indexPath)
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The idea is that a UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView. Whilst the former's delegate methods seem broken, the latter's are still being called. Some experimentation produced this test.

Just an idea :) You may prefer to subclass UITableView rather than extend, to localise the hack.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. Enjoy.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell.EditingStyle {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    return .none;
    } else {
        return .delete;
    }
}
```